# How can I call two external .js and two external .css to just one div?

Tags: javascript, html, css

How can I call two external .js and two external .css to just one div?

For example, "https://code.xxx.xx/xxx-3.1.0.min.js", "https://code.xxx.xx/xxx-3.1.0.js", "https://xxx.xx/xxx/xxx.css" and "https://yyy.yy/yyy/yyy.css" for only what is inside this div

Note 1, I do not want these external js and css to work on the rest of the page, just inside that div.

note 2, that I also do not want the js and css I use on the rest of the page to work inside that div with id = "test"

Comment: The only way is to use the [Shadow DOM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components/Using_shadow_DOM) perhaps using [Web Components](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components)

Comment: Even shadowDOM does not sandbox JS files. It only protects CSS.

Comment: Can you be a little clearer as to what "can I call" means? You don't **call** CSS. You would apply the CSS to a DIV. You also don't **call** JS files. You load them and then call a function from that file.

Comment: Are you sure you don't want to use an IFRAME? That's the usual way to keep a section of a page totally independent.

Answer (score 0):

What you are probably looking for are [iframes](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_iframe.asp):

Put the code you wanted in that div onto another page of your website, for example into an iframes path.
Then use an iframe instead of your div element:

```
<iframe src="/iframes/test.html" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```